# How to use the API Name in Marketo integration?

Tags: json, rest, marketo

I have created a custom activity in Marketo with a field called `Permalink` and its API name is `permalink`.

Using the `POST /rest/v1/activities/external.json` endpoint, I am sending the following JSON to add a custom activity.

```
{
    "input": [
        {
            "activityDate": "2016-10-17T10:32:41+00:00",
            "activityTypeId": 100005,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "apiName": "permalink",
                    "name": "Permalink",
                    "value": "https://facebook.com"
                }
            ],
            "leadId": "492",
            "primaryAttributeValue": "Test FB post"
        }
    ]
}
```

This call is successful and returns the following message:

```
{
    "requestId": "81d8#157d25cb121",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2287,
            "status": "added"
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

**But**, when I **don't** send the `apiName` in the JSON (according to the [documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Activities/addCustomActivityUsingPOST) it is indeed optional), it works as expected as well.

I am curious to know where and how to use the `apiName`. What is the use for it and why is it optional? If there is any documentation, kindly point me to that since I couldn't find much information.